# Using REGEX to create duplicates in find / replace window of an

Tags: regex, replace, sas, enterprise-guide

I have a string of words separated by tabs.

lets say I want to surround each word with brackets and add "sum"

so I use the find/replace function to replace \t with )\t, sum(.

so from

> A B C D E

I get

> sum(A), sum(B), sum(C), sum(D), sum(E)

But what if I want to duplicate the words.

i.e.

go from:

> A B C D E

to

> sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B, sum(C) as C, sum(D) as D, sum(E) as E ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions

didn't work.

The environment in question is SAS EG 7.1

Comment: Maybe something like `name = prxchange('s/([A-Z]+)/sum($1) as $1/', -1, name);` and then ``name = prxchange('s/\)(?!$)/),/', -1, name);``?

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for something that will work in the Find / Replace window. I frequently need to surround column names with sum or datepart or some other function and it gets tedious to add as <name> to each.

Comment: Are you looking for something that will work in the Enterprise Guide code editor window?  Or something you can use in an actual SAS program?  Also show what you tried that did not work.

Comment: Ok, what I suggested should work anywhere: Step 1) replace `([A-Z]+)` with `sum($1) as $1`, 2) replace `\)(?!$)` (or `(?m)\)(?!$)`) with `),`

Comment: I end up with sum($1) as $1, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot figure out how to make the editor generate code for you why not create a macro to do it for you in the code you submit to SAS?

Your example would translate into a macro like this:

```
%macro sumlist(varlist);
%local i word sep;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
  %let word=%scan(&varlist,&i);
&sep.sum(&word) as &word
  %let sep=,;
%end;
%mend sumlist;
```

Which you could then call in your program to generate part of an SQL statement.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as 
  select %sumlist(a b c d e)
  from have 
;
quit;
```

Then if you really need your editor to help you create the code you are only talking about adding a constant prefix `%sumlist(` and suffix `)` around the selected list of variable names.